# Save salt with hashed password

Tags: java, pbkdf2

I'm saving hashed password with this pattern in the Database:

```
PkGzO4WINLmDHLeXETzsjoxdtNzz0ngR3ux4P5E61go=:ffApiGPDwAuZL+a/GO8ooPt2JxXk2CXumlyhC0eZd8Q=
 Pattern-> HashedPassword:Salt
```

After character **":"** is salt.

This is configuration for hashing:

```
private static final String DEFAULT_ALGORITHM = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512";

private static final int DEFAULT_ITERATIONS = 2048;
private static final int DEFAULT_SALT_SIZE = 64;         // 32-byte/256-bit salt
private static final int DEFAULT_KEY_SIZE = 64;
```

Is it a bad way? Do exist a better way?

Comment: I think your approach is a recommended method for protecting passwords in a database. The default values you mentioned for the algorithm, iterations, salt size, and key size are reasonable. Newer algorithms like bcrypt, scrypt, or Argon2 have gained popularity due to their stronger resistance against GPU-based attacks. If you can apply it may be worth considering these algorithms as potential alternatives to PBKDF2.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to store salts! Given that you have the following function for creating your hashes:

```
string crypt(string password, string salt);
```

if you create a salted hash for your password like:

```
string hashedPassword = crypt("mypassword", saltFunction("md5"));
```

you can verify passwords like:

```
string hash = crypt("mypassword", hashedPassword); 
if(hash == hashedPassword) {
   // Password is correct
}
```

This is common practice and widely used in Postgres.